# Sort function random output

Tags: sorting, perl

I'm trying to write a sort function in Perl. I need "name_iwant_last" to be the last in a sorted hash.

```
%libs = (
"00000000000","00000000000",
"aaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaa",
"AAAAAAAAAA","AAAAAAAAAA",
"name_iwant_last","name_iwant_last",
"zzzzzzzzzzzzz","zzzzzzzzzzzzz",
"ZZZZZZZZZZZ","ZZZZZZZZZZZ",
"9999999999","9999999999"
);

sub lib_sort {
  #print "cosa ordino ";
  #print $libs{$a};
  #print $libs{$b};
  #print "\n";
  return 1 if (index($libs{$a} , "name_iwant_last") != -1);
 return -1 if $libs{$a} < $libs{$b};
  return 0 if $libs{$a} == $libs{$b};
  return 1 if $libs{$a} > $libs{$b};
}

foreach my $lib (sort lib_sort values %libs) {
    print $lib;
    print "\n";
}
```

But, when I run this code, the print is in random order.

Expected:

```
aaaaa
AAAAA...
name_iwant_last
```

Resulted:
random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add `use warnings` to your code, then you'll see a few warnings like this:

> Argument "ZZZZZZZZZZZ" isn't numeric in numeric lt (<) at sort line 20.
> Argument "AAAAAAAAAA" isn't numeric in numeric lt (<) at sort line 20.
> Argument "zzzzzzzzzzzzz" isn't numeric in numeric lt (<) at sort line 20.
> Argument "aaaaaaaaaaa" isn't numeric in numeric lt (<) at sort line 20.
> Argument "name_iwant_last" isn't numeric in numeric lt (<) at sort line 20.

You're comparing strings, but you're using the numeric comparison operators (`<`, `==`, `>`). If you switch to using string comparison operators (`lt`, `eq`, `gt`) then it will work as expected.

And **always** have `use warnings` and `use strict` in your code.

**Update:** As discussed in the comments, a better way to write this is to use `cmp` (which is the string comparison version of `<=>`).

```
sub lib_sort {

  return 1 if (index($libs{$a} , "name_iwant_last") != -1);
  return $libs{$a} cmp $libs{$b};
}
```

Comment: You could use `lt eq gt`, or you could just use `cmp`, which returns -1, 0, or 1 depending on order. I.e. `return $libs{$a} cmp $libs{$b}`.

Comment: @TLP: Oh, yes, I should have mentioned that too.

Comment: `-$libs{$a}` ....? That will always return -1, when I am testing it? What is the purpose of that minus sign?

Comment: @TLP: It was a typo. Fixed now. Please feel free to just edit away any idiocies that you find in my answers :-)

Comment: I will keep that in mind for next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

A working version of my code:

```
%libs = (
"00000000000","00000000000",
"aaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaa",
"AAAAAAAAAA","AAAAAAAAAA",
"name_iwant_last","name_iwant_last",
"zzzzzzzzzzzzz","zzzzzzzzzzzzz",
"ZZZZZZZZZZZ","ZZZZZZZZZZZ",
"9999999999","9999999999"
);

sub lib_sort {
  #print "cosa ordino ";
  #print $libs{$a};
  #print $libs{$b};
  #print "\n";
 if (index($libs{$a} , "name_iwant_last") != -1) { 
     return 1;
    } elsif (index($libs{$b} , "name_iwant_last") != -1) { 
     return -1;
    } elsif ($libs{$a} lt $libs{$b}) { 
     return -1;
    } elsif ($libs{$a} eq $libs{$b}) { 
     return 0;
    } elsif ($libs{$a} gt $libs{$b}) { 
     return 1;
    }
}

foreach my $lib (sort lib_sort values %libs) {
    print $lib;
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).